# What should I do if I want to find out more information as to why an answer was deleted by a moderator?

Tags: discussion, comments, flags, moderator-tools

> *Note: I am asking as a general question for all sites, not specifically for Stack Overflow as in this case.*

I came across [this deleted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74964563/12349734):

[image]

and I was *wondering why* was the answer deleted?

Now, being that I follow the [flutter](/questions/tagged/flutter) tag, I can *kind of* tell the answer *wasn't* a good one, and maybe even incorrect. But that's not my point. My question is:

**What should I do if I want to find out *why* an answer was deleted?**

What I can do:

- Leave a **comment** to the mod that deleted it and ask why.
- **Flag** the post as "In need of moderator intervention" - but that doesn't seem correct.

Comment: You can ask on the per-site meta for the site, which in this case is [Meta Stack Overflow](//meta.stackoverflow.com). In cases where high-quality content is mod-deleted, generally the answer is either because it was plagiarized from elsewhere or it was posted by a user who is evading a suspension or indefinite ban from the site (some such users use "good" content to "prove" they shouldn't be banned; that's still considered evasion).

Comment: As you noticed, it was not a good answer and the reason is [ChatGPT](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy) wrote it.

Comment: @RobertLongson So why wasn't the user banned?

Comment: I see that my question was downvoted, is there anything that I can add?

Comment: Depends on the moderator, some are more lenient than others. The policy page does say at the end - at their discretion.

Comment: Maybe someone thought you asked it on the wrong site. Stack Overflow site questions [go on its Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: @RobertLongson Got it. But my question was in general for _all_ sites, not specifically for SO. I guess the downvoter didn't realize..

Comment: I didn't downvote or vote to close, but I'm guessing another reason for the downvote is because people don't consider it worthwhile for others to ask why others' posts were deleted.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Thanks for your helpful comments. Do you think I should delete this post since the community has accepted it wrongly?

Comment: You would use this tag, on MSO: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/specific-answer

Comment: Questions about deleted posts in specific site should go in that site meta, they're off topic here. That's why there are downvotes here and close votes.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars But I think the community miss read the last line of my question: That I'm asking this as a _general_ question, what should I do if I want to find out more information. This wasn't specific to SO or any other site.

Comment: 99% of the question talks about one specific post. That's not example, that's the whole question. Adding one line saying otherwise can't change that, sorry. You might be able to re-phrase the question but I'm not sure it has merit at this point.

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars I understand, I guess that I miss worded the question... (So now my question will also be deleted since I didn't word it correctly? or can I just edit this question?)

Comment: I don't think it should be deleted, and you do have answer. Editing might give some more (up)votes, but not sure it will attract enough reopen votes, even if done right. You can edit, guess my point is don't build your hopes too high that it will lead to reopening and positive score.

Comment: I deleted it because it was produced with chatGPT, which is banned.

Comment: A moderator flag is definitely not the way to go. If the moderator frequents the local site chatroom, I'd start by asking there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reasoning behind a moderator action may be questioned on a site's meta, as explained in [the help center page on moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators). You can't comment on deleted posts, and raising flags is unhelpful for several reasons: other users can't see the response so if there are more users questioning the reasoning behind an action, a mod would be handling several flags instead of one meta post, and the character limit for custom flag responses is tiny, so meta allows for more elaborate responses.

One other option that you have is to use chat. You already say you know it's not a good answer, and that it is wrong. There's no loss in its deletion, and you probably weren't going to argue it should be undeleted/shouldn't have been deleted. If you're just asking 'why' to satisfy some curiosity, chat may at times work just as well as meta.